# Set network adapter ip/dns addresses without netsh and WMI?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

I've been going through MSDN to determine how to set the ip/dns addresses of a network adapter without using netsh and WMI but I've not found anything. Does anyone know what kind of methods I would need to use for this?
Preferably for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: If you want to know how *netsh* is implemented, run [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-options) against the binary, listing its imports. That'll give you an idea of the APIs that tool uses to implement its functionality.

Comment: Thanks, never heard of that before, will look into that :)